# Removing element from 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

If I had a 2D array list and wanted to remove one element from it, would this be the correct way?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> List = new ArrayList<>();
List.remove(1); //remove first index
```

starts as

```
[
  [Hi],
  [Bye],
  [How],
  [Good]
];
```

becomes

```
[
  [Bye],
  [How],
  [Good]
];
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "element". A row could be an element (inner array are elements of outer array). A cell is also an element (elements of inner arrays). What you're doing is remove a row. So you decide, is it correct?

Comment: Take care of java naming convention. Variables should Start with lowercase character.

Comment: What is the question? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Lists in java are zero based!!! So your example is wrong

Comment: huh the site changed what I had, it was supposed to be [[Hi],[Bye],[How],[Good]] as the start list and then i wanted to remove element [Hi] from the list to make [[Bye],[How],[Good]].

Comment: @JasonGao They only unnecessarily added whitespace, it does not change the premise of the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not correct, and extremely unintuitive.

First off, indices are 0-based, that is, the first element in a `Collection` is indexed by `0`.
So you should remove `0`, not `1`.

You also shouldn't name a local variable nor field in PascalCase, since by convention classes are what should be named in PascalCase. It's hard to understand whether or not you're calling a static method `remove` in the `List` interface, or you're calling an instance method `remove` in a field/variable called `List`.
Every programmer will think you're doing the former.

Fields and local variables by convention are named in camelCase.

Comment: so is .remove(0) the correct method to removing the first inner array of the outer array? Or is there some other line of code to do this?

Comment: `remove(0)` is the correct way to remove the first _element_ of any _List_. You're not working with arrays, but lists.